# How to use jQuery to dynamically update IDs after cloning a table row?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When triggered, the 3rd (bottom) row of a table is cloned. In the CSS, this row (#tr3) is set to: display:none;  Here is the table row I am cloning:

```
<tr name="tr3" id="tr3">
    <td><input type="text" name="dt1" id="dt1"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fn1" id="fn1"></td>
    <td><a href="#" name="change1" id="change1">change</a></td>
    <td><a href="#" name="del1" id="del1">delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

This is the JQuery code to clone the row. Not mine, sadly, so I don't understand all of it.

```
$("table tr:nth-child(4)").clone().find("input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) {
    return id + count;
});
```

Specifically, how does the function in line 2 work - what is the underscore?

Here's what I came for, though. How can I:

1. change the style to display:block for cloned rows, and
2. update the ids of the anchor tags in the cloned rows. The IDs of the input fields Do update (e.g. fn1 => fn11, fn12, fn13, fn14, etc).

Thank you.

Comment: Do you really need `id`? What do you use it for?

Comment: Looks like a case of using IDs instead of classes. I definitely have to question if you even need IDs here.

Comment: Table allows users to add documents to a DB. For each new doc, a new table row. Submit will push to a PHP file that loops thru the docs and adds to the DB. Each new row must allow user to "change" the doc (input file) and reset the field. Therefore, I need to know which "change" tag is being clicked to pass along that value. The IDs DO incr on two of the cells (dt and fn) but not on the clickable anchor links.

Comment: You could have a single ID at the `<tr>` level that you can increment, but it still doesn't explain the need for IDs in the input fields and the `<a>` links. And if I understand correctly, if the ID corresponds to a primary key in the table, it should be a hidden field that you blank out when you clone a new table with 0 IDs in your HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just for clarity:

```
var $clone = $("table tr:nth-child(4)").clone();
```

1. How to change the style to `display:block` for cloned rows?

   ```
   $clone.show();
   ```
2. How to update the ids of the anchor tags in the cloned rows.

   ```
   $clone.find("a, input").each(function() {
     $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) {
       return id + count;
     });
   });
   ```
3. In the jQuery code above, how does the function in line 2 work - what is the underscore?

   The underscore (`_`) is a valid [ECMAScript's identifier name](http://es5.github.com/#x7.6) and it is used simply as a placeholder to be able to grab the second argument (`id`.)

And everything altogether (untested.)

```
$("table tr:nth-child(4)")
  .clone()
  .show()
  .find("a, input").each(function() {
    $(this).val('').attr('id', function(_, id) {
      return id + count;
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You never actually access the cloned row on its own.  You would have to assign it to something, e.g.

   ```
   $clonedRow = $("table ...").clone();
   ```

   *then* you can run all of the other methods and finally append `$clonedRow` to the DOM, possibly with

   ```
   $clonedRow.insertAfter("table ...")
   ```
2. You need to somehow strip off the last digit(s), possibly with a regex:

   ```
   return id.replace(/\d+$/, '') + count;
   ```
3. The `_` is just a placeholder.  It's not used, so the writer of the code chose a nondescript variable name since something is required in the declaration to get at the `id` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. I now understand the underscore. Digesting the rest of your answer.